# SSRS How to define parameters as 7 days ago plus 1 hour

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report made using SSRS and SQL Server and I have set a StartDate and EndDate parameters for the report.

I have set the default value for StartDate as `=DateAdd("D", -7, Today())`
I have set the default value for EndDate as `=DateAdd("H", 1, Today())`

How can I add 1 hour to the StartDate Parameter?

I've tried

```
=DateAdd("H", 1, (DateAdd("D", -7, Today())))
```

Would that work? I'm currently testing it but the report usually takes 6 hours to run.

Comment: Yes, DateAdd returns a Date and you are using the return value as the actual parameter of a function that takes a Date.

Comment: Yes it should work.

Comment: *Would that work?* Why not check using a different report, or create a quick report with an expression displaying the value? SO isn't a code checking site; that would be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: @Larnu I did not know Code Review existed. Thanks for raising awareness.

Answer (score 2):

Do the date math in hours instead of days.

```
=DateAdd("H", -169, Today())
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that work? You can always try that in SQL Server. The answer is yes :o)

Although, you should use the NOW() function instead of the TODAY() function (see the **Update** below).

SQL Server:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HH, 1, DATEADD(DD, -7, GETDATE()))
```

SSRS/VS:

```
DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, -167, Now())
```

**Update:** To Larnu's point, Today() will default as a date format of MM/DD/YYYY. If you only subtract 167 hours from Today, then the field will show in date time, but the result will be incorrect as it will show 1:00 AM for the time. So use the NOW() function, instead of TODAY(). The result will be 167 hours from the current time and will be in the format of MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

Also, you can make the change in the parameter field and click on the Preview in VS to see these changes. You would not need to run the report to see this change. That, or I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That'll work differently in SQL Server. `Today()` returns a date (thus `2018-04-05` today), however `GETDATE()` in SQL Server returns a datetime. For me, that would be something like `2018-04-05 21:38:47.517`. That's over a 21 hour difference :)

Comment: I thought he wanted to test the functionality. If you do something like DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour,-169,Today()), then the date field will convert to date time.

Comment: -167 would show 1:00am as the time (which is the same result as the original expression from the question), not 11:00pm. -169 would show 11pm, and the date would be one day prior, so 8 days before today. This doesn't change the essence of your point though: it would display a fixed time that does not change if the report is viewed at different times, which may or may not be intended behavior (hard to tell from the info provided in the question).

Comment: @CBlack I already updated my answer to reflect that. Use the NOW() function, instead of TODAY().

Comment: @J Weezy I know that, but you said that using -167 with Today() would return 11pm which is not correct. -169 would return 11pm on the 8th day prior to today. -167 returns 1am. Not hugely important, but since we're talking about the difference between one day and another day, I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @CBlack Ah, I see what you are saying. Yes, that was an omission on my part as I updated the number from -169 to -167 to account for the OP request of 7 days ago plus 1 hour without updating the time impact. Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected it.