# SQL Server 2014 - How to get date range of 7 days ago plus 1 hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, getdate

I need to pull up details from 1 hour past midnight, 7 days ago. But I'm not getting the results I need.

My code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE BusinessDay >= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, (DateAdd(DAY, -7, getdate())))  --@StartDate
  AND BusinessDay <= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, getdate())  --@EndDate
```

When I give an actual time like below, I get the results I need:

```
WHERE BusinessDay >= '2018-04-04 00:01:000'  --@StartDate
  AND BusinessDay <= '2018-04-11 00:01:000'  --@EndDate
```

I need to pass the dates in a parameters in SSRS. But clearly, the syntax is wrong in SSRS too.

I tried the below code but I get an error message:

```
WHERE BusinessDay >= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, (DateAdd(DAY, -7, CAST(getdate() as date))))  --@StartDate
  AND BusinessDay <= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, CAST(getdate() as date))  --@EndDate
```

The error message: *The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.*

So, I also tried the below code but got no results:

```
WHERE BusinessDay >= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, (DateAdd(DAY, -7, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))))  --@StartDate
  AND BusinessDay <= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))  --@EndDate
```

Comment: Replace `GETDATE()` with `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS How to define parameters as 7 days ago plus 1 hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680577/ssrs-how-to-define-parameters-as-7-days-ago-plus-1-hour)

Comment: @JWeezy Not exactly... That's subtracting 167 hours (from the current time), this is getting 1am 7 days ago.

Comment: The link by J Weezy is what he needs.  He is trying to do this in SSRS.  The answer provided is actually dropping the timestamps, which he wants to keep, and sql server is perfectly capable of keeping, as is SSRS as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: The error message you posted is because of the cast.  Dates don't have hours, and you're trying to add an hour to the date.

Comment: It didn't work in SSRS. So I'm trying to execute each step manually without the parameters in SQL Server. Hence I'm trying to find how to enter the relative Date instead of hard coding the date.

Comment: You've casted `getdate()` as date.  You cannot `DATEADD` an hour to a date datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HH, 1, FORMAT(DATEADD(DD, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), N'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:000'))
```

SQL Server 2014 introduced the FORMAT() function to make it easier to return/display data types in a formatting that you want without having to do a whole bunch of math with the formulas. Note: the format pattern is case-sensitive.

```
GETDATE() = '2018-04-11 18:20:00.000'

Formula Result: '2018-04-04 01:00:00.000'
```

For more information on the FORMAT() function, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

`getdate()` has a time component.  So, remove it first:

```
WHERE BusinessDay >= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, (DateAdd(DAY, -7, cast(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime)))) AND --@StartDate
      BusinessDay <= DateAdd(HOUR, 1, cast(CAST(getdate() as date) as datetime))  --@EndDate
```

Comment: I think it needs another cast as datetime for the dateadd function.

Comment: I get an error message: The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.

Comment: You want to keep the timestamps if you're trying to get your values within an hour range.  Casting to date drops the time stamps.

Comment: So, I did a test, and this works, but not all in a single line.  Declare a variable for @today DATETIME = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE);  This will get you today with a 12am timestamp.  use that variable instead of trying to do the cast within the dateadd function.

Answer (score 0):

With a little tweak to Gordon's answer to avoid an error produced by doing a CAST within the DATEADD function:

```
DECLARE @td DATETIME = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE);
DECLARE @td1AM DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @td);
DECLARE @weekAgo1AM DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @td1AM);
```

Then do your query with this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE BusinessDay >= @weekAgo1Am  -- @StartDate
AND BusinessDay <= @td1AM -- @EndDate
```

For SSRS, via the answer linked in your comments, use TODAY():

```
DECLARE @td DATETIME = TODAY();
DECLARE @td1AM DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @td);
DECLARE @weekAgo1AM DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -7, @td1AM);
```

And the same query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE BusinessDay >= @weekAgo1Am  -- @StartDate
AND BusinessDay <= @td1AM -- @EndDate
```

Comment: Thank you. But, in SSRS, I'm required to give an option to change the Dates. I had set the Dates parameters with default values of getdate - 7 + 1 hour. Obviously, that was wrong. How would I give the default values in parameters in the SSRS report?

Comment: @user1777929 are the users giving you a date, and you still need from 1 am to 1 am of each date?  or just from their specified datetime to another specified datetime?

Comment: I still need from 1 am to 1 am of each date. The users would just like to select a StartDate and an EndDate from the parameters boxes.

Comment: @user1777929 In that case you need to write a procedure that takes their selected dates as input parameters.  Then you just declare the parameters as DATETIMEs and add 1 hour to each and execute the same query that is posted here.  DATEADD works the same in SSRS as in SSMS, the only difference before was the TODAY() function instead of casting GETDATE() as DATE to force the midnight timestamps.